# CORS blocking content only on Firefox and Safari and only onClick()

Tags: reactjs, firefox, safari, cors

I'm building a `react.js` app and I think I have CORS issues but I can't create a server. I'm therefore using a proxy (such as this one `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/${myApiEndpointHere}`).

When I'm using **Chrome**, I'm able to successfully fetch the data. However when I'm using **Firefox** or **Safari**, I get these issues listed below. This CORS issue (on Firefox and Safari) seems also to only happen when the scroll is triggered because both for Firefox, Safari and Chrome, I'm able to get my content and log in to the console.

[image]

Firefox:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   https://res.cloudinary.com/dcpexd0zo/image/upload/v157136216…pes/Capture_d_e%CC%81cran_le_2019-10-17_a%CC%80_21.26.11.jpg.
>   (Reason: missing token ‘user-agent’ in CORS header
>   ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight channel).
>
> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   https://res.cloudinary.com/dcpexd0zo/image/upload/v157136216…pes/Capture_d_e%CC%81cran_le_2019-10-17_a%CC%80_21.26.11.jpg.
>   (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
>
> TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

Safari:

> Request header field User-Agent is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
>
> Fetch API cannot load
>   https://res.cloudinary.com/dcpexd0zo/image/upload/v1571362166/shapes/Capture_d_e%CC%81cran_le_2019-10-17_a%CC%80_21.26.11.jpg
>   due to access control checks.
>
> https://res.cloudinary.com/dcpexd0zo/image/upload/v1571362166/shapes/Capture_d_e%CC%81cran_le_2019-10-17_a%CC%80_21.26.11.jpg
>   Failed to load resource: Request header field User-Agent is not
>   allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
>
> Error: The error you provided does not contain a stack trace.
>
> Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: Request header field
>   User-Agent is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

Answer (score 0):

You should read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers

And add this header to the response from the proxy server: `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *`

Comment: Can I do this from the client-side? With a proxy like this: https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/?